# Python: Remove repeated code for repeated action in Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium

I am working in Python with Selenium and have to do this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
```

I am doing this because there are 4 elements on the page that have this CSS Selector "`#results .page_block_sub_header_count`". And I want to get the result of the 4th one.

Is there a good way I could put this into code? I do not want 4 similar lines. And I believe this is not considered a good code practice.

Comment: How about `find_elements_by_css_selector()`? (Note the additional "s"!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` (note the "s") to locate multiple elements matching a locator - CSS selector in your case:

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
```

`results` would be a *list of `WebElement` instances*, you can iterate over it and get, say, a text:

```
for item in results:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: OP wants just the 4th (last?) one. No need to loop, just reference the 4th... `print(results[3].text)`.

Comment: @alecxe As OP `want to get the result of the 4th one` why should we fall back on **find_elements_**?

Comment: @DebanjanB we don’t gave to and nth-of-type or other similar selectors is definitely an option as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the following code (just a case):

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#results .page_block_sub_header_count")

for index in range(len(elements)):

    elements[index].text
```

PS: @alecxe's code is better for usage.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `HTML` it is tough to provide you the best fit solution. How ever as I can see from your tried out code, you have used :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count')
```

This essentially means, the `node` with `id` as **`results`** has atleast **4** childnodes with `class` as **`page_block_sub_header_count`**. So to construct the best fit `css_selector` we are missing the information regarding the **`tagName`** which contains the class **`page_block_sub_header_count`** which will be available in the `HTML DOM`.

Still if you `want to get the result of the 4th one` you can use the following line of code :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#results .page_block_sub_header_count:nth-of-type(4)')
```

Comment: @user3349993 I fail to understand when you `want to get the result of the 4th one` why would you fall back on **find_elements_**